# remove selected class after get Ajax data and draw() DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, reload

I'm trying to reload the selected row when user click on `Edit` button from database, but after reload the row and call `table.row().data(response).draw(false);`, remove `selected` class
from the row.

```
$.ajax({
    type: callMethod,
    url: url + '/' + value,
    timeout: 3000,
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        
        //create notification
        var notifyOptions = {
                title: '<h4>Error 500</h4>',
                text: '<p>'+ textStatus + '. ' + errorThrown + '.</p>',
                type: 'error'
        }
        
        show_notification(notifyOptions);
        
    },
    success: function(response) {
        
        table.row().data(response).draw(false);
        
        table.row(selected).select();
        
    }
}).done(function(data) {

    table.row(selected).select();

});
```

I writed `table.row(selected).select();` in `success` and `done` but that doesn't work.

I used too:

```
table.on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    $(table.context[0].aoData[selected].nTr).addClass('selected');
});
```

but I understand I can't use that. because that has error in remove row.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, that work in DataTables, I override functions:

After `edit` and `view` row:

```
$.ajax({
    type: callMethod,
    url: url + '/' + value,
    timeout: 3000,
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        
        //create notification
        var notifyOptions = {
                title: '<h4>Error 500</h4>',
                text: '<p>'+ textStatus + '. ' + errorThrown + '.</p>',
                type: 'error'
        }
        
        show_notification(notifyOptions);
        
    },
    success: function(response) {
        
        table.row().data(response).draw(false);
        
        table.on( 'draw.dt', function () {
            $(table.context[0].aoData[selected].nTr).addClass('selected');
        });
        
    }
}).done(function(data) {

    ...

});
```

After `remove` row:

```
$.ajax({
    type: callMethod,
    url: url + '/' + value,
    timeout: 3000,
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        
        //create notification
        var notifyOptions = {
                title: '<h4>Error 500</h4>',
                text: '<p>'+ textStatus + '. ' + errorThrown + '.</p>',
                type: 'error'
        }
        
        show_notification(notifyOptions);
        
    },
    success: function(response) {
        
        table.off( 'draw.dt');
        
    }
}).done(function(data) {

    ...

});
```